# Can't set the attribute "trainable_weights" likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property

Tags: tf.keras

when i define my own layers with `tf.keras`,like this:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.input_spec = [InputSpec(shape=input_shape)]
    shape = (input_shape[self.axis],)
    #print('shape:',type(shape))
    init_gamma = self.scale * np.ones(shape)
    self.gamma = tf.Variable(init_gamma,name='{}_gamma'.format(self.name))
    print('type',type([self.gamma]))
    self.trainable_weights=[self.gamma]
```

It raise a bug in the `tf/python/keras/base_layer.py` that I can't set the attribute "trainable_weights"  likely because it conflicts with:

```
 an existing read-only @property  of the object. Please choose a different name
```

What should I do?

Comment: [Possible duplicate. Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343563/cant-set-the-attribute-trainable-weights-likely-because-it-conflicts-with-an)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't set the attribute "trainable\_weights", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343563/cant-set-the-attribute-trainable-weights-likely-because-it-conflicts-with-an)